# some browser not support scroller

Tags: html, layout, scroll

I'm running a web site code,`Crome` and `IE` works fine,display full page and able to scroll it,but in `mozilla Firefox` the scroller not present.
I'm attaching screens,please review these images.

but in mozilla scroller not present.what type of problem is this? how to remove it in JSP and servlet code.

my Html code is:

```
<title> GleeWorks.net </title>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.2" src="js/stm31.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.2" src="js/check_session_timeout.js"></script>
<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel=stylesheet>
```

I've using I frame also in all the tables:

```
<IFRAME name="contentFrame" id="contentFrame" SRC="<c:out value="${defaultContentURL}"/>" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 
                        scrolling=no WIDTH=780 height="1000" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"
                        style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden;border:none;">
                    </IFRAME>
```

Comment: please provide some code ... mostly the container div style ...

Comment: this looks like an HTML issue, please post HTML that reproduces the problem. Removing java/jsp/servlets tags as they shouldn't be related.

Comment: wait,i'm editing this question.

Comment: How can the scrollbar be viewed, when the page content does not go beyond page's limits?

Comment: Look at the upper image. It seems like the page's limits are as default.

Comment: no default page is ,i just give u default page link.please check this link https://www.gleeworks.net

Comment: @eis i've added code,please review it.

Comment: can i show head.html code

Comment: @dev we asked for *HTML* code, not the JSP

Comment: @dev and the url you've given does not show the page in question if you're not registered, "Access to forms is controlled, giving you the utmost in confidentiality."

Comment: you have to set height=" " and in place of overflow:hidden change overflow:-moz-scrollbars-vertical ar overflow-y: scroll;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily an html issue as I've run into this problem when developing through Microsoft Sharepoint and I was able to solve it by using:

**CSS File:**

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Option 2: Directly in your html page:**

```
<style type="text/css">


     html {
               overflow-y: scroll;
        }

</style>
```

Comment: @dev Alright, I've actually got to get to sleep but if you need any help just post a comment here and I'll see it in a few hours. This should do the trick though.

Comment: Also try if problem not solve ar problem related to mozilla firefox overflow:-moz-scrollbars-vertical